# Sequelize Many to Many Relationship Filtering

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models with many to many relationship (`JobPost`, `Skill`), where I want to search for all `JobSkill`s that contains a specific `Skill`. Up to this point, I have come with the following,

JobPostModel:

```
 static associate(models) {
   this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'authorId', as: 'author' });
   this.belongsToMany(models.Skill, { through: models.Job_Skill, foreignKey: 'jobPostId', otherKey: 'skillId', as: 'skills' });
   this.belongsToMany(models.JobCategory, { through: models.JobPost_Category, foreignKey: 'jobPostId', otherKey: 'jobCategoryId', as: 'categories' });
   this.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: models.JobPostSubscription, foreignKey: 'jobPostId', otherKey: 'userId', as: 'subscriptions' });
 }
};
JobPost.init({
 authorId: {
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   allowNull: false
 },
 title: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING,
   allowNull: false
 },
 body: {
   type: DataTypes.TEXT
 },
 budget: {
   type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
   defaultValue: 0,
   validate: {
     min: 0
   }
 },
 location: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING
 },
 private: {
   type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
   defaultValue: false
 },
 deadline: {
   type: DataTypes.DATE
 },
 status: {
   type: DataTypes.ENUM(enumJobStatuses),
   defaultValue: enumJobStatuses[0]
 }
}, {
 sequelize,
 modelName: 'JobPost',
});
```

SkillModel:

```
class Skill extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      this.Users = this.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: models.User_Skill, foreignKey: 'skillId' });
    }
  };
  Skill.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Skill',
  });
```

Job_Skill Model:

```
class Job_Skill extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  };
  Job_Skill.init({
    jobPostId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    skillId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Job_Skill',
    timestamps: false
  });
```

Main Code:

```
models.JobPost.findAll({
   include: {
        model: models.Skill,
        as: 'skills',
        attributes: ['id', 'title'],
        through: { where: { skillId: req.query.skillId } }
    }
})
```

But this returns all posts.
I have tried to use `{ where: { '$skills.id$': req.query.skillId } }` which returns only `JobPost`s that has only one `Skill` matching the skillId.
I want `JobPost`s to return where any of the skills of that post matches the skillId.  So, if a post has 2 skills and the given skill matches one of the skills, it will be in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be only in the where statement.
I did something similar with:

`skillId: { [Sequelize.Op.in]: skillsList }`

Considering you have an array of skill ids/names there on `skillsList`.